# Sql server CTE get parent's children then update children with parent value

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

How do I loop through all children and update one column for all the nodes? For example if I am on the parent level with column "OrganisationLevelID". If I update the "OrganisationLevelID" on the parent row it should propogate to the children hence all children of parent as well as the childrens' children should then have the same value in "OrganisationLevelID".

**I have the following cte**:

```
 WITH cte as
(select h.Name, h.ID, h.OrganisationLevelID, h.parentId
From organisations h
WHERE ID = '3eea8c17-1bfd-46d5-9ea9-2d11652d23a4'
UNION ALL 
select p.Name, p.ID, p.OrganisationLevelID, p.parentId
FROM organisations p
INNER JOIN cte c ON c.Id = p.parentId)
SELECT *  FROM cte
```

This gets the parent child hierarchy and works fine.

How do I update the children values so that they all have the parent's "OrganisationLevelID"?

```
 WITH cte as
    (select h.Name, h.ID, h.OrganisationLevelID, h.parentId
    From organisations h
    WHERE ID = '3eea8c17-1bfd-46d5-9ea9-2d11652d23a4'
    UNION ALL 
    select p.Name, p.ID, p.OrganisationLevelID, p.parentId
    FROM organisations p
    INNER JOIN cte c ON c.Id = p.parentId),
  cteupdate as(**Some magic here**)
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results really help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for updating actual records in the `Organisations` table, I believe you can try this:

```
;WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT h.Name
        , h.ID
        , h.OrganisationLevelID
        , h.parentId
    FROM organisations h
    WHERE ID = '3eea8c17-1bfd-46d5-9ea9-2d11652d23a4'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT p.Name
        , p.ID
        , c.OrganisationLevelID  -- note that I changed the alias from "p" to "c" to use the parent's value
        , p.parentId
    FROM organisations p
    INNER JOIN cte c
        ON c.Id = p.parentId
    )
UPDATE org
SET OrganisationLevelID = cte.OrganisationLevelID
FROM organisations org
INNER JOIN cte
    ON org.id = cte.id
```

You can use the below sample code to see what will happen, specifically the value in orgValueId from the parent row will "propagate" to all of its children and descendants:

```
create table #t (id int, parentid int, orgValueId varchar(10));

insert into #t values (1, null, 'x'), (2, 1, 'o'), (3, 1, 'm'), (4, 2, 'v'), (5, 3, 'p');

select *
from #t;

with cte as (
    select id
        , orgValueId
    from #t
    where parentid is null

    union all

    select t.id
        , c.orgValueId
    from cte c
        inner join #t t on c.id = t.parentid)
update t
    set orgValueId = c.orgValueId 
from #t t
    inner join cte c
        on t.id = c.id;

select *
from #t;
```

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you Radu! My biggest mistake was not selecting the parent's OrganisationLevelID from the cte when creating the hierarchy.